# Which confidence interval is correct?

Tags: statistics, time-series

I have time series predictions with 50% and 90% confidence intervals. 50% of observations lie below the 50% confidence interval (IIUC, this should happen only 25% of the time), but all observations lie within the 90% confidence interval. Which one should be trusted and why?

Edit: I should add that it's the later observations that are outside the 50% interval and that there are just over 40 observations in total. How many observations should there be in order to trust the intervals?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean "tolerance intervals" as you are talking about intervals containing a certain proportion of future observations. If they were both calculated correctly, you should "trust" both, but to different degrees. Obviously the 50% interval will not contain as many points as the 90% interval. So, if missing points is important to you, then go with the 90%. However, if achieveing that degree of certainty is too costly, then you will need to use a lower level of coverage. Its really an economic decision of what level of risk you are comfortable with. There is no one-size-fits all answer.

Comment: Since observations aren't passing the 50% intervals but are passing the 90% intervals, does that mean they weren't calculated correctly or something else is broken somewhere?

Comment: Not necessarily: First (I should have asked this earlier) I don't know how many observations we are talking about - a small number of observations gives a good chance to "out of whack" results, but that may be spurious. It is not correct to say that 25% should be below the 50% interval. You need to know the prediction distribution used to develop the intervals to answer that question. For example, you could have 40% below the 50% interval and 10% above it. You are assuming that the observations are from a symmetric distribution when you say you expect 25% below the 50% interval.

Comment: As a broad check, you can use the fact that $P(x_i \notin I_{50\%})=0.5$ So if you have N total observations, with M observations outside of the interval, then the p-value of this result, given a correct interval, is $\sum\limits_{i=M}^N Binomial(i;N,0.5)$

Comment: at this time, there are just over 40 'observations' (in quotes since really each observation is an aggregate of real observations). If there are 40% below and 10% above the 50% interval, wouldn't that mean the model is over-predicting? What rationale could there be not to move the interval down such that 25% is above and below the 50% interval?

Comment: If a 50% interval has 50% of the observations it's not over predicting. You have identified the fact that an interval estimate of a given confidence level is not unique... You need ancillary criteria to select one of the infinite possible intervals. Your intuition about moving the interval downwards means you prefer central intervals with equiprobable upper and lower errors, however there are other criteria as well, such as minimizing the length if the interval for a given confidence or maximizing the likelihood of the interval

Comment: Sorry, I'm misusing terminology. Looking at both the 50% and 90% intervals again, I notice that the length above the 50% and within the 90% is equal to the length below the 50% and within the 90%. Does this mean that the prediction distribution is symmetric?

Comment: No, but it's suggestive. You can answer definitively by looking at the formula you used to create the intervals. If you have just been given them, then you don't have enough information to say much with certainty - although i'd suspect that they are using Gaussian prediction intervals, in which case they would be symmetric. We may be getting a bit away from your orignial question. The bottom line is that you can assess your itervals using either the prediction distribution (if you have it) OR the binomial test I gave earlier. The choice between 50% or 90% is a subjective matter.